# Мне нужно настроить динамическое изменение захаркодженого filterLayer[0]

Tags: javascript

```
const LayerChangeControlsTabContainer = ({ enabledLayers, handlerChangeLayerSetting, changeDisplayOfMapItem }) => {
  const filteredLayer = enabledLayers.filter((item) => item.isSelected === true);
  debugger
  // выводятся вначале настройки из customSettings слоя, потом, если выполнится условие, настройки вида отображения объектов,
  // потом настройки стиля карты
  return (
    <div>
      <LayerChangeControlsField selectedLayer={filteredLayer[0]} changeLayerSetting={handlerChangeLayerSetting} />
      {filteredLayer[0].layerSchema.possibleLayersToRender?.length ? (
        <LayerChangeDisplayField selectedLayer={filteredLayer[0]} changeDisplayOfMapItem={changeDisplayOfMapItem} />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Что значит "динамическое изменение захаркодженого"?

Comment: filteredLayer[0] - задано значение 0. нет никаких проблем когда я открываю только одну страницу(потому что order у нее равен 0) но когда я пытаюсь открыть вторую страницу(а точнее настройки) order у второй страницы равен 1. из-за этого у меня крашится страница. мне нужно каким то образом, как я понял, вместо 0 в filteredLayer[0] сделать так что бы он считывал присвоенные order и не крашился(я джун, постарался объяснить как могу)

Comment: Объясни зачем в этой строке тернарный оператор filteredLayer[0].layerSchema.possibleLayersToRender?.length

Comment: честно говоря не знаю, не я писал код. могу лишь сказать что при debbuge этой части выдает undefined, а удалив эту часть на первый взгляд ничего не меняется

Comment: Не возможно обратиться к свойству через точечную нотацию при наличии тернарного оператора в его названии, результат undefined. Соответственно в этом условии всегда будет null. Если в названии свойства есть (?) то обращаться нужно так filteredLayer[0].layerSchema["possibleLayersToRender?"].length. Посмотри название ключей Object.keys(filteredLayer[0]); Object.keys(filteredLayer[0].layerSchema); что выводит?